# Avoid Subquery returned more than 1 value error in a table valued function

Tags: function, sql-server-2008-r2, subquery

Is there a way to rewrite this query without getting error?: Subquery returned more than 1 value.

This is query is used in a LEFT JOIN in a table-valued function.  Per requirement, I need to by default pull two scenario IDs (if parameter value is NULL or empty)

```
DECLARE @pScenarioName AS VARCHAR(30)
select 
    externalID, 
    PropertyAssetId, 
    LeaseID, 
    BeginDate 
from ae11.dbo.ivw_Leases 
WHERE PropertyAssetID IN 
(select ID from AE11.dbo.PropertyAssets where scenarioID IN
(CASE WHEN isnull(@pScenarioName, '') = '' 
            THEN (select top 2 ID from rvw_Scenarios  where Name like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
                    AND LEN(Name) = 8
                    order by Name desc)
            ELSE    
                (select ID from aex.dbo.rvw_Scenarios
                where [Name] IN (@pScenarioName))
          END)
)
```

Comment: Do the two `ScenarioID`'s need to be the last two that match that criteria? In other words, do you need to `ORDER BY Name DESC` in your subquery?

Comment: I need to pickup the latest scenario name. Example:  2017_B02, 2017_B01.  As long as I can use desc order, I should be able to pull associated scenarioID.  Is this possible by simply adding desc in your query below?

Comment: I believe you would be able to as long as you specify `TOP n`. See updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but I use a similar approach when dealing with parameters. Of course, this won't necessarily work if the order of the ID is crucial in your second subquery.

```
SELECT   ExternalID
    ,PropertyAssetId
    ,LeaseID
    ,BeginDate 
FROM ae11.dbo.ivw_Leases 
WHERE PropertyAssetID IN 
    (SELECT ID 
        FROM AE11.dbo.PropertyAssets 
        WHERE scenarioID IN 
            (SELECT TOP 2 ID
                FROM rvw_Scenarios
                WHERE (@ISNULL(@pScenarioName,'') = ''
                        AND Name LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
                        AND LEN(Name) = 8)
                ORDER BY Name DESC
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT ID FROM aex.dbo.rvw_Scenarios
                WHERE  (@pScenarioName IS NOT NULL)
                    AND [Name] IN (@pScenarioName)))
```